# Detecting encoding before opening a file

Tags: character-encoding, common-lisp, file-handling, sbcl

I got a file with an unknown character encoding. Running `file -bi test.trace` returns `text/plain; charset=us-ascii` but using

```
(with-open-file (stream "/home/*/test.trace" :external-format :us-ascii)
 (code-to-work-with-file))
```

gives me an exception:

```
:ASCII stream decoding error on
#<SB-SYS:FD-STREAM for "file /home/*/test.trace"   {10208D2723}>:

  the octet sequence #(194) cannot be decoded.    [Condition of type SB-INT:STREAM-DECODING-ERROR]
```

How can I detect the encoding of a file before opening it?

I can open the file with `emacs`,`less` and `nano` just fine so it seems to be a miss-detection of the encoding or a difference in what `file` and `sbcl` think an encoding should look like.

I currently avoid this problem by forcing every file to have a utf8 encoding with `vim +set nobomb | set fenc=utf8| x file-path`. But even after this `file` still thinks it is an us-ascii encoding. Additional this is not a valid permanent solution, rather a dirty hack to make it work.

Comment: "How can I detect the encoding of a file before opening it?" You have use the specification, convention or agreement from wherever it came from. An encoding cannot be detected because there always multiple valid answers based on the sequence of byte values. Besides the current contents of a file is only one sample of the contents. If you just want to avoid exceptions and allow some bytes to be misinterpreted, you can use CP437. You can improve your guess by trying all the hundreds of encodings, seeing which don't give exceptions and comparing the interpretations. ┬

Comment: @TomBlodget this is not the answer I was hoping for but consequently the answer I was looking for if there is no true detection mechanism that works. Post this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed in prorgammers stackexchange in [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187169/how-to-detect-the-encoding-of-a-file),

> Files generally indicate their encoding with a file header. There are
>   many examples here. However, even reading the header you can never be
>   sure what encoding a file is really using.

I looked for trace files in my system and found this one but this not have any funny thing

2016-06-22 13:10:07 ☆ |ruby-2.2.3@laguna| Antonios-MacBook-Pro in ~/learn/lisp/stackoverflow/scripts
○ → file -I resources/hello.trace
resources/hello.trace: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

2016-06-22 13:11:50 ☆ |ruby-2.2.3@laguna| Antonios-MacBook-Pro in ~/learn/lisp/stackoverflow/scripts
○ → cat resources/hello.trace
println! { "Hello, World!" }
print! { concat ! ( "Hello, World!" , "\n" ) }

So With this code I can read it:

```
CL-USER> (with-open-file (in "/Users/toni/learn/lisp/stackoverflow/scripts/resources/hello.trace" :external-format :us-ascii)
           (when in
    (loop for line = (read-line in nil)
         while line do (format t "~a~%" line))))
println! { "Hello, World!" }
print! { concat ! ( "Hello, World!" , "\n" ) }
NIL
```

or even in chinese or whatever it was:

[image: rare output]

we can read the ascci character like this

```
CL-USER> (format nil "~{~C~}" (mapcar #'code-char '(194)))
"Â"
```

Or any other strange character so it seems that can be characters with accents I add this to the file:

```
 println! { "Hello, World!" }
print! { concat ! ( "Hello, World!" , "\n" ) }
Â
patatopita
```

and I get the same error:

:ASCII stream decoding error on

for "file /Users/toni/learn/lisp/stackoverflow/scripts/resources/hello.trace"
  {1003994043}>:

the octet sequence #(195) cannot be decoded.
   [Condition of type SB-INT:STREAM-DECODING-ERROR]

So at this point you can work with contitions and restarts, to change the character, there is an option, I not specialist in this kind of code but there could be a restart with

```
Restarts:
 0: [ATTEMPT-RESYNC] Attempt to resync the stream at a character boundary and continue.
 1: [FORCE-END-OF-FILE] Force an end of file.
 2: [INPUT-REPLACEMENT] Use string as replacement input, attempt to resync at a character boundary and continue.
 3: [*ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
 4: [ABORT] abort thread (#<THREAD "repl-thread" RUNNING {10050E0003}>)
```

Input-replacement, if not try wit european like latin-1 or ISO....

```
CL-USER> (with-open-file (in "/Users/toni/learn/lisp/stackoverflow/scripts/resources/hello.trace" :external-format :latin-1)
           (when in
    (loop for line = (read-line in nil)
         while line do (format t "~a~%" line))))
println! { "Hello, World!" }
print! { concat ! ( "Hello, World!" , "\n" ) }
Â¬
patatopita
NIL
```

And it should work, good luck

so let's read with european charset